# how to programmatically add optgroup to select2

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I am adding option values to a pre-initialized select2 object like this:

```
function updateFilter() {
    var $element = $("#filter");
    var counterOption = 0;
    Object.keys(genderMap).forEach(function (key) {
        if (key !== "null") {
            var $option = $("<option></option>");
            $option.val(counterOption);
            $option.text(key);
            $element.append($option);
            counterOption = counterOption + 1;
        }
    });
    $element.trigger("change");
}
```

I need to add more values from other dictionaries, so my goal is to put options from different maps inside an optgroup tag, to help the user understand what value belongs to what group.

I have found something in SO, but all those answers were relying on JSON. What is the right way to add the optgroup tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official docs show you how to add `<optgroup>` and `<option>` tags using the plugin's `data` option. https://select2.github.io/options.html#how-should-nested-results-be-formatted

In your case, I would approach like so:

```
function updateFilter() {
    var $element = $("#filter");
    var counterOption = 0;

    // prepare your new data object
    var data = [
      {
        text: 'OptGroup 1: Gender',
        children: Object.keys(genderMap).filter(filterFn).map(mappingFn) // assuming global genderMap
      },
      {
        text: 'OptGroup 2: Age',
        children: Object.keys(ageMap).filter(filterFn).map(mappingFn) // assuming global ageMap
      },
      {
        text: 'OptGroup 3: Eye Color',
        children: Object.keys(eyeMap).filter(filterFn).map(mappingFn) // assuming global eyeMap
      }
    ];

    // filters 'null' keys
    function filterFn(key){
      return key !== 'null';
    }

    // transforms the array of keys into an array of {options}
    function mappingFn(key){
      var option = {id: counterOption.toString(), text: key};
      counterOption++;
      return option;      
    }    

    // re-initialize select2 with new data
    $element.select2("destroy"); // destroying may not be necessary
    $element.select2({
      data: data
    });
}
```

Comment: it works fine in building the dropdown with optgroups and options, however for some reason I cannot select them anymore... it's really weird...

Comment: @user299791 I added a `filterFn` for getting rid of the 'null' keys